WinForms .NET 8 Textbox data binding to BindingSource in Designer: how?
Doing experiments testing the usability of WinForms and .NET 8 for conversion of legacy .NET 4.8 projects I run into peculiar blind spots:
On just an empty Form with both a TextBox and a BindingSource (dragged from the Toolbox Panel), it seems there is no way of setting the TextBox 'Text' property data binding to a property of the BindingSource instance (like it used to be possible with .NET 4.8).
Of course, programmatically this is still possible using e.g.
this.textbox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.bsMain, "name");

(where 'bsMain' is the name of Form1's BindingSource) but that would defeat the whole purpose of instantiating the BindingSource from the Toolbox in the first place.
Is this still supported/am I overlooking something?

It is possible. Select the TextBox, go to its (DataBindings) selector in the PropertyGrid, open the (Advanced) dialog, select the property to bind to and the source of data from the Binding drop-down. This does the same exact thing you're doing in your code, the only difference is that the code is generated in the .Designer.cs file instead of the main .cs file (the BindingSource may be initially bound to a type; in this case you have to reset its DataSource after the InitializeComponent() call)

I tried that, but the named BindingSource control of the form (visible at the bottom of the Form's designer surface) ('bsMain') simply does not show up as a data source that can be selected. The BindingSource itself at that design-time stage is not connected to any underlying DataSource yet. That can only happen later in the Constructor remainder.

How do you bind a Control to a source of data that has no defined source, so no data fields are actually defined? You have to select a data source for your BindingSource. Could be a class object. As mentioned before, it doesn't need to actually contain data; as also mentioned, in this case the DataSource is set to a Type, which provides the data fields to which you bind to. The data can be set at any point after the InitializeComponent() call, since that's when the BindingSource Component and the Controls are created

Our typical scenario is databinding to a DataTable or DataView; the BindingSource's DataSource to those is set after the InitializeComponent() call. The data binding in the designer then just involves setting the e.g. Textbox's data source and data member to the BindingSource and a named (string) field/column of that DataTable of DataView. This has been working very well, doing the same in .NET 8 seems not possible in the designer, but it is using code. I just don't understand why the designer won't show the Form's BindingSource as a possible DataSource candidate like you suggested.

I don't understand how a Binding can be created if there's no defined data Column to bind the Property of a Control to. If you have a DataTable, I assume you use a typed DataSet in the designer, a ViewModel or whatever else. Otherwise, what do you need a BindingSource Component (which, BTW, is automatically generated when you select whatever source of data) for?

The DataTables/Views we use sometimes are dynamic  / non-typed. Doing a databinding in the designer to a BindingSource that hasn't got its DataSource set yet (at design time nor when calling InitializeComponent) will simply result in the code line 'this.textbox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.bsMain, "name");' in the designer cs file. And that is very useful, as it allows us to set the column fields without having a typed object source. The BindingSource can be used this way without even knowing at design-time what the data source ultimately will be.

Well, I don't exactly understand your requirements; anyway, I don't think there's a VS dialog that allows to specify a source Field / Property / Column of a source of data that doesn't have a data source (sic). I don't remember that this could be possible in .NET Framework either. A BindingSource is not a source of data per se, unless you have set its DataSource property, to either a concrete object or a Type that provides Properties / Columns

Look at Databinding with the OOP Windows Forms Designer

Update: After testing, you can manually input bsMain-Name in Text option.

As   Jimi said,  even in  .NET Framework,   there's no opton that allows to specify a source Field / Property / Column of a source of data that doesn't have a data source.
You need to bind DataSource for bsMain first  so that there is bsMain option in textbox databinding.

Considering that you need to set the DataSource dynamically, you can set the bsMain DataSource none after generate bsMain-Name.


That's exactly the answer I was looking for, this works; it needs the name of the BindingSource with ' - ' (including the spaces) and then the name of the field/member/column. Thank you very much! Is this documented somewhere?
